# .xinitrc, .xsession don't work (commands not run)

Tags: ubuntu, display-manager, dwm, xinit

A quick summary:
I installed Ubuntu (Current LTS - 22.04)
I wanted to change the window manager from the default one to "dwm"
I installed dwm via apt, it works correctly,
The problem is - when i try to make some customizations (like setting up a wallpaper on start, etc) .xinitrc and .xsession files seem to not get executed properly.
this is my .xinitrc file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#
# global xinitrc file, used by all X sessions started by xinit (startx)

echo TEST >> ~/logfile.txt

# invoke global X session script
. /etc/X11/Xsession
```

the log file never gets appended (xsession contains the same content)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you still using X? Maybe you are on wayland already. Furthermore, xinitrc is only executed when you use startx to manually start the x display server.